# I have a problem with "ADD" and "INSERT" functions in database

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

I wanna ask you, how can I fix this code? I have a problem with "ADD" and "INSERT" functions in database. I can only delete from database, but "add and insert" functions do nothing.

this is my about.php file.

```
    $mode = 'add';
$about = '';

if(isset($_GET['edit']) && is_numeric($_GET['edit'])){

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `about_me` WHERE `about_me`.`id` =".$_GET['edit'];
    $result_about = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result_about) == 1) {
        $mode = 'edit';

        $about = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_about);
    }
}

$apie = '';    
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){         
    if(isset($_POST["apie"])){           
        $apie = trim($_POST["apie"]);   
    }

}
elseif($mode=='edit') {
    $apie = $about['about'];
}

if($mode=='add') {
    if(($apie!='')){
        $sql = 'INSERT INTO about_me(about)
        VALUES ("'.$apie.'")';
        mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        header('Location:about.php');
        die();
    }
}
elseif($mode=='edit') {
    if(($apie!='')){
    $sql = "UPDATE `about_me` SET `about` = '".$apie."' WHERE `about_me`.`id` = ".$_GET['edit'];    
    mysqli_query($conn, $sql) ;

    }
}
```

<..>

```
            <input type = "text" name = "apie" value = "<?php echo $apie; ?>">

            <br><br>
            <input type = "submit" name = "submit" value = "Gerai">
            <br><br>
```

I checked mysql error, with https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_error.asp, and then it insert in my DB. I think there is code foult, but I don't know where.

Comment: Check for the Error - https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_error.asp

Comment: Incidentally, also get acquainted with [little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com).

Answer (score 0):

You have a slight error with your first query, you can't use parentheses next to the database selector, I'd recommend creating a separate file with a database connection that you can refer to as `$conn`, your first query should look like this:

```
    $sql = "INSERT INTO about_me
        VALUES (?)";
```

Also, you should look into [prepared statements](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp) for your queries, instead of inserting them directly you use a question mark`?` to which you bind the parameter/parameters. This helps prevent SQL injections!

Hope this helps!:)

Comment: `code` $sql = 'INSERT INTO about_me (about)
   VALUES ('.$apie.')'; `code`

but it not helped to me.  i have seperate file with a database connection and there refer  $conn.